# What does a VPN Tunnel offers other than encryption?

Tags: vpn, tunnel

A VPN tunnel is end to end encrypted.
But does it gurantee to provide features other than encryption, such as low latency, low jitter etc?

Comment: Not all VPN tunnels are encrypted.  Some of my clients use VPN tunneling just to deal with addressing.  I understand that British Telecoms ADSL structure uses L2TP just for addressing.  https://kitz.co.uk/adsl/equip2.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tunnels change the network topology. They let routers A and B be logically adjacent even if they don’t have a physical connection.  They also let you run one type of network over another type of network.

Example uses:

1. Run IPv6 network over IPv4-only infrastructure.
2. Connect “internal security zone” networks over “external” routers.
3. Logically connect slave devices (such as access points) to a controller.

A VPN tunnel is a tunnel with encryption. So it has all the features of a tunnel while adding data secrecy.

Low latency and low jitter are not on the tunnel or VPN tunnel feature list.  The act of encapsulating /encrypting /decrypting may increase latency and jitter. The encrypted traffic may also cause QOS flags in the original traffic to not be visible to the underlying network infrastructure.

Comment: The "external" network (e.g. Internet) might not even care about your QoS scheme & flags at all.

Answer (score 0):

No guarantees of low latency or jitter unless that is provided by the underlay or transport network.